# makefile error: opening dependency file .d/file_name.Td: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, makefile, g++

I am trying to adapt a makefile ([that I found here](https://gist.github.com/maxtruxa/4b3929e118914ccef057f8a05c614b0f)) that automatically generates dependencies. However, when I run `make` I get the following error message:

```
t@t-XPS-13-9365:~/pf/test$ make
g++ -MT .o/test_resamplers.o -MD -MP -MF .d/test_resamplers.Td -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I/usr/local/include/UnitTest++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I../include -c -o .o/test_resamplers.o test_resamplers.cpp
test_resamplers.cpp:155:1: fatal error: opening dependency file .d/test_resamplers.Td: No such file or directory
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:66: recipe for target '.o/test_resamplers.o' failed
make: *** [.o/test_resamplers.o] Error 1
```

Perhaps I am using the wrong `DEPFLAGS` variable in my makefile. I did switch the compiler from `clang++` in the example to `g++`. Here's my makefile:

```
# output binary
BIN := run_tests

# source files
SRCS := \
    main.cpp test_cf_filters.cpp test_resamplers.cpp test_rv_eval.cpp \
    test_rv_samp.cpp test_utils.cpp

# intermediate directory for generated object files
OBJDIR := .o
# intermediate directory for generated dependency files
DEPDIR := .d

# object files, auto generated from source files
OBJS := $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(basename $(SRCS)))

# compilers (at least gcc and clang) don't create the subdirectories automatically
$(shell mkdir -p $(dir $(OBJS)) >/dev/null)

# C++ compiler
CXX := g++
# linker
LD := g++

# C++ flags
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11
# C/C++ flags
CPPFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I/usr/local/include/UnitTest++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I../include
# linker flags
LDFLAGS := "-L../bin" "-L/usr/local/lib"
# flags required for dependency generation; passed to compilers
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td
# libraries
LDLIBS := -lpf -lUnitTest++

# compile C++ source files
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@
# link object files to binary
LINK.o = $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
# precompile step
PRECOMPILE =
# postcompile step
POSTCOMPILE = mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

all: $(BIN)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -r $(OBJDIR) $(DEPDIR)

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo available targets: all dist clean distclean install uninstall check

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.o) $^

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(PRECOMPILE)
    $(COMPILE.c) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(PRECOMPILE)
    $(COMPILE.cc) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cc
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cc $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(PRECOMPILE)
    $(COMPILE.cc) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cxx
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cxx $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(PRECOMPILE)
    $(COMPILE.cc) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

.PRECIOUS = $(DEPDIR)/%.d
$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;

-include $(DEPS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the object directory with this line:

```
$(shell mkdir -p $(dir $(OBJS)) >/dev/null)
```

but you don't create the `DEPDIR` anywhere, so when the compiler tries to create a file there it fails.

You could add this line to make the dependency directory:

```
$(shell mkdir -p $(DEPDIR))
```

Or, add it into the previous shell function.